# pytest autouse=True not working correctly? simply returning ["a"]

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, pytest-fixtures

Here's the code

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def first_entry():
    return "a"

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def append_first(first_entry):
    return [first_entry]


def test_string_only(first_entry):
    assert first_entry == ["a"]
```

simply modified from [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request)

I've been staring at it for 40 minutes, cannot figure out why in test_string_only it still recognize first_entry as "a" instead of ["a"] ? I thought the fixture with autouse=True will be executed in each test case?

error logs

```
======================================================= FAILURES ========================================================
___________________________________________________ test_string_only ____________________________________________________

first_entry = 'a'

    def test_string_only(first_entry):
>       assert first_entry == ["a"]
E       AssertionError: assert 'a' == ['a']

test_fixture2.py:24: AssertionError
```

Comment: The fixture with `autouse=True` is supposed to do something, e.g. to have some side effect. If it just returns a value, where should that value go?

Comment: could you elaborate your question please? sorry couldnt understand it. I thought the fixture will be processed first by append_first so always return [first_entry]?

Comment: I removed my comments and put them in a separate answer instead, hopefully this clarifies it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make an answer from my comments, as this may indeed be confusing for more people.

The problem here is the example in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-fixtures-you-don-t-have-to-request) mentioned in the question, that was used as a template:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def first_entry():
    return "a"

@pytest.fixture
def order(first_entry):
    return []

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def append_first(order, first_entry):
    return order.append(first_entry)

def test_string_only(order, first_entry):
    assert order == [first_entry]
```

This is *not* a good example to base your code on. What happens here is that the fixture `order` returns an empty array, and the fixture `append_first` adds an entry to this array. Due to the fact that `append_first` is always called, it always appends that entry to the array instance returned from the first fixture. The fact that it also returns it is irrelevant for this case - it would only be needed if the fixture was called directly.

So if using instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def append_first(order, first_entry):
    order.append(first_entry)
    # does not return anything
```

would have the same effect, namely the side effect of altering the array object returned by the first fixture.

This is unexpected and confusing, and very similar in my opinion to the known anti-pattern of [passing an array as a default argument](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html).

As mentioned, fixtures with `autouse=True` make only sense if they have a side effect, and they usually don't return anything. They may return a value, but that value will only be used if the fixture is used directly, otherwise it will be discarded.

In your example, you simply don't need an `autouse` fixture, but can just reference the fixture directly, as already mentioned in the other answer:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def first_entry():
    return "a"


@pytest.fixture
def append_first(first_entry):
    return [first_entry]


def test_string_only(append_first):
    assert append_first == ["a"]
```

Note also that the mentioned `pytest` example [has been changed](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/fixtures.html#fixture-errors) in the current documentation to not return a value, and received a better explanation.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for answering, indeed I got confused by the example cause it's *returning* a value, so I thought it doesn't modify the existing list in place. After knowing that it behaves the same without the return, it make sense that it's just referencing to the same list. Thanks for extensive explanation!

Comment: shouldn't the assert be `assert append_first  == ["a"]`?

Comment: Thanks @Vulwsztyn - that was of course a typo (probably copy and paste)! Corrected now.